# PHP and MySQL on IIS7: can't find php_mcrypt.dll in php.ini

Tags: iis-7

I have installed PHP with Microsoft Web PI. Then I installed mysql.

According to http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/353/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7/

I have to Uncomment the following lines by removing the semicolon:
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll

But there is no extension=php_mcrypt.dll in php.ini installed by web PI so should I add it by hand then where ? and where should I check that php_mcrypt.dll exists ?

Seems nobody knows, should better ask on Microsoft forum ?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) add it to php.ini by hand. Actually getting a copy of the DLL is trickier, though - I'm in the midst of a search for it myself right now. I have an older version that isn't working with v5.3.4 of PHP.

Comment: i found a download for [php_mcrypt.dll](http://www.dlldll.com/php_mcrypt.dll_download.html) In case you are still looking for it ^^

Comment: Please give some details, as it stands the answer isn't of much use to OP.

Comment: The question is not only where to download it but also where it should be on the user's system and how it should have been installed in the first place. Merely a download link is not helpful.